# Can I transit in São Paulo having separate flight ticket

Tags: transit, brazil, gru, sao-paulo

I am a holder of Djibouti passport and currently live in Qatar.
I am planing to visit Ecuador, and I want to make this trip booking two different flight tickets:

- first, a flight from Doha to São Paulo.
- and next, a flight from São Paulo to Quito.

I talked to Qatar Airways, and they told me it's ok to have two separate tickets. But: is there any problem having two different tickets in São Paulo airport?

Answer (score 5):

[Timatic says](https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=dj&destination=ec&transit=br):

> #### TRANSIT INFORMATION
>
> ### Transit Countries
>
> ### Brazil
>
> #### Visa
>
> Visa required
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Passengers with a connecting flight booked on the same ticket in transit. Exception: This TWOV facility does not apply at Curitiba (CWB), Florianopolis (FLN), Porto Alegre (POA), Porto Seguro (BPS) or Salvador (SSA).

So you would need to visa if self-connecting (separate tickets).

Comment: This makes sense: if you book two tickets by yourself, you probably cannot label your luggage to the final destination, so you will have to go through immigration, collect your luggage and circle back to the check-in desk for the second flight. So the visa requirement is not just a formality, in all likeliness you have to actually enter the country to make the 'connection'. And once you pass immigration with you bags, you could just walk out and forget about the second flight ticket, even if you are _saying_ that you will not do that and stay inside the airport.